# Using a POJO to initialize the content of an ArrayController

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

The data for my template is, for the time being, set programmatically, using a POJO, with some constant values:

```
var DROPDOWN_MENU = [
    { 'text' : 'Profile',  'icon' : 'fa fa-eye dd-icon',     'href' : '/profile' },
    { 'text' : null },
    { 'text' : 'Logout',   'icon' : 'fa fa-signout dd-icon', 'href' : '/signup/clear_session_and_logout' },
];
```

The following template:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle opener" {{bind-attr id="elId"}} data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i {{bind-attr class="myclass"}}></i>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    {{#each entry}}
        {{#if entry.text}}
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{entry.href}}"><i class="{{entry.icon}}"></i>{{entry.text}}</a></li>
        {{else}}
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The following controller:

```
App.DropdownController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    elId    : CNST.DROPDOWN_ELID,
    content : DROPDOWN_MENU,
    myclass : 'fa fa-power-off fa-2x',
});
```

And the following view:

```
App.DropdownView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'navbar/dropdown',
    controller: App.DropdownController,
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var controller = this.get('controller');
        var elId = controller.get('elId');
        if (DEBUG) { console.log('DropdownView.didInsertElement > activating dropdown for elId=%s', elId); }
        $('#' + elId).dropdown();
    }
});
```

But the template has no access to the content defined by the POJO (because it is not an ObjectArray?). How can I force the content in my ArrayController using the data in the POJO?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using a view and controller to accomplish this? A component would seem like a more natural fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using a component instead, in any Javascript:

```
var DROPDOWN_MENU = [
    { 'text' : 'Profile',  'icon' : 'fa fa-eye dd-icon',     'href' : '/profile' },
    { 'text' : null },
    { 'text' : 'Logout',   'icon' : 'fa fa-signout dd-icon', 'href' : '/signup/clear_session_and_logout' },
];

App.MyDropdownComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    elId    : CNST.DROPDOWN_ELID,
    menu : DROPDOWN_MENU,
    myclass : 'fa fa-power-off fa-2x',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var elId = this.get('elId');
        if (DEBUG) {
          console.log('DropdownView.didInsertElement > activating dropdown for elId=%s', elId); }
        $('#' + elId).dropdown();
    }
});
```

And specify and accompanying template, in `app/components/my-dropdown.hbs`:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle opener" {{bind-attr id="elId"}} data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i {{bind-attr class="myclass"}}></i>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    {{#each entry in menu}}
        {{#if entry.text}}
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{entry.href}}"><i class="{{entry.icon}}"></i>{{entry.text}}</a></li>
        {{else}}
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

You can take it further by specifying the `classNames` instead of binding them manually in the templates. See [customising class names](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-class-names).

Furthermore, instead of hard coding the the same POJO like above, you can instead pass in any value you like. See [customising attributes](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-attributes).